# bind method on click event of "LabelLink" control in WPF - Caliburn

Tags: wpf, hyperlink, caliburn.micro

Hi I have problem to bind method on click event of "LabelLink" control. I use pseudeo LabelLink control, I think everybody know this solution with textBox and hyperlink.

Here is my code:

```
<TextBlock Margin="10,12,10,4">
    <Hyperlink Name="RegLink"
               NavigateUri="http://registracia.azet.sk/"
               Micro:Message.Attach="[Event Click]=[Action OpenDefaultBrowser(NavigateUri)]"
               FontSize="12">Registrácia</Hyperlink>
```

Problem is that I can bind method only on framework element.

I get this compile error:

```
Cannot attach type "ActionMessage" to type "Hyperlink". Instances of type "ActionMessage" can only be attached to objects of type "FrameworkElement".
```

I search with google, bud didn’t find any suitable solution.

Thank for advice.

I try make a fake linkLabel with textBlock or Label control but they don’t have click event handler.

Answer (score 12):

I have adapted @Rick's answer to Caliburn.Micro

In TestView.xaml

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="HyperlinkButton" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <ContentPresenter/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <Button Style="{StaticResource HyperlinkButton}" Focusable="False"
        cal:Message.Attach="[Action NavigateTo('http://www.stackoverflow.org')]">
        <TextBlock>
            <Hyperlink Focusable="False">www.stackoverflow.com</Hyperlink>
        </TextBlock>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

In TestViewModel.cs

```
public void NavigateTo(string url)
    {
        Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(url));
    }
```

I am using this way in my application and it works. Hope it helps you.

Comment: An old question, but still relevant: The problem with this approach is that it causes problems with text wrapping: a hyperlink can start at the end of one line, and continue at the beginning of the next--buttons can't do that.

Answer (score 6):

You can embed your `Hyperlink` in a `Button` that doesn't look like a button in order to get a `Click` event that occurs on a `FrameworkElement`:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="HyperlinkButton" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <ContentPresenter/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Name="button1" Style="{StaticResource HyperlinkButton}" Click="Button_Click" Focusable="False">
            <TextBlock>
                <Hyperlink NavigateUri="http://www.stackoverflow.com" Focusable="False">
                    StackOverflow
                </Hyperlink>
            </TextBlock>
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Perhaps you can adapt this technique to Caliburn.Micro.

Comment: I try it, But get exception:  {"'System.Windows.Documents.Hyperlink' is not a Visual or Visual3D."}

Comment: I tested the example on WPF3.5 and WPF4 with seeing your exception.  Nevertheless, I updated the example to include a `TextBlock` wrapper around the `Hyperlink` and made the `Button` and `Hyperlink` not focusable.  See if any of those changes help.

Comment: I get System.Windows.Documents.Hyperlink' is not a Visual or Visual3D exception too with TextBlock wrapper around Hyperlink in WPF4. Any resolve to this phenomenon?

Answer (score 1):

I  Did this in vs2017

Method In ViewModel

```
        public void LinkClick(string url)
    {

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(url));
        }
    }
```

Then as above in the View XAML namespace declaration at the top

xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"

```
           <Grid>
               <Grid.Resources>
                  <Style x:Key="HyperlinkButton" TargetType="Button">
                       <Setter Property="Template">
                           <Setter.Value>
                               <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                   <ContentPresenter/>
                               </ControlTemplate>
                           </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                   </Style>
               </Grid.Resources>
                <!-- Collapsed so you can not see it ! -->
                <TextBlock x:Name="LinkTarget" Text="http://www.google.com" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                <!-- Bound the TAG to the Collapsed TextBlock Text then pass that into the method in VM -->
               <Button Tag="{Binding ElementName=LinkTarget, Path=Text}" Style="{StaticResource HyperlinkButton}" Focusable="False"
                       cal:Message.Attach="[LinkClick($this.Tag)]">
                    <TextBlock>
                        <Hyperlink Focusable="False">Read More ...</Hyperlink>
                    </TextBlock>
               </Button>
           </Grid>
```

Hope this helps some one else! I know its an old post but, I landed here!